# How to fix error for installing GoogleMaps 2.1.1 Unrecognized archive format iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoapods

I am rookie in iOS and i am trying to install **GoolgeMaps** by pod. But show me error like this:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Installing GoogleMaps (2.1.1)

[!] Error installing GoogleMaps
[!] /usr/bin/tar xfz /var/folders/mf/60_klly5641fb71xqlp7xjc40000gn/T/d20170121-42827-ord5gk/file.tgz -C /var/folders/mf/60_klly5641fb71xqlp7xjc40000gn/T/d20170121-42827-ord5gk

tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

and this is my podfile:

```
target "ProjectName" do
    platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

end
```

And i am using Objective C and iOS 8. Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: I have checked my connection and vpn and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Download it manually from  [google developer dashboard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) or using that link :[Google map SDK IOS](https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/5a212b0fa429156f-GoogleMaps-2.0.1.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your country you need to use VPN to connect to Google Developer.