# cocoapod ERROR tar: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

i have try to install firebse in my project but i have receive this errors

```
[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/bin/tar xfz /var/folders/t9/69xnfpsj4dd_gkst2lkt7_2c0000gn/T/d20170616-1202-vwchlz/file.tgz -C /var/folders/t9/69xnfpsj4dd_gkst2lkt7_2c0000gn/T/d20170616-1202-vwchlz

tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

this below is my pod file :

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'weather' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Firebase'

end
```

KingFisher and Alamofire install successfully but Firebase does not

Comment: I'm having the same issue and accepted answer won't help me. how did you solve your problem?

Comment: @mehdok may be you need anti filter,this work for me

Comment: unfortunately this works for me too!

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124681/4797289), you need just use VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `podfile` is ok, but there seem to have been some network issue while you ran `pod install/update`. Do the following to solve this issue:

1. `pod cache clean --all`
2. `pod update`

Comment: this did not solve the problem for me, do you have any idea?

Comment: @mehdok, you could always re-run the pod install and see if it helps you.

Comment: I think I had some network issue, it solved by itself, tnx.