# install pod 'Google/SignIn’

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

My pods worked perfectly up until I added Google Signin:`pod 'Google/SignIn'`.
When I did pod install, I got the following error:

> Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)
>
> [!] Error installing FirebaseAnalytics [!] /usr/bin/tar xfz
>   /var/folders/m2/78wzkkfj7ql6_lfzn79gjkcw0000gn/T/d20170819-9010-16gvjyx/file.tgz
>   -C /var/folders/m2/78wzkkfj7ql6_lfzn79gjkcw0000gn/T/d20170819-9010-16gvjyx
>
> tar: Unrecognized archive format tar: Error exit delayed from previous
>   errors.

what should I do please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124681/4797289), you need just use VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, could you please try with below(Change Test with your Target name)

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘Test’ do

pod 'Google/SignIn'

end
```

Comment: Can you share your podfile or its content

Comment: I found the problem.googledeveloper site is ban in my country I should use vpn to install pod